# Call method of a user control on Button click in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a MVVM application. Well, it's not *exactly* 100% pure MVVM for various reasons, but I'm trying to follow its most important principles.

I want to call `Foobar` method (which executes purely view-related logic) of `MyUserControl` class contained in `MyUserControl.xaml.cs` on `Button` click. Both `Button`and `MyUserControl` instance exist in the same `PageView` (whose data context is some irrelevant view-model).

`<Button Click="Foobar"/>` doesn't work, because the stub appears in `PageView.xaml.cs` instead of `MyUserControl.xaml.cs`.

Is it possible to link `Button`'s Click event with `Foobar` invocation in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to do it via XAML you can try to add a public property ICommand to your MyUserControl class and execute Foobar method in this command. Then bind it in xaml of PageView like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=FoobarCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yhea it is possible. Use the ICommand as it is supposed to in MVVM.
You then can simply call you method like that:

```
<Button Command={Binding CFoobar} .../>
```

With CFoobar being the Command for your Method in your Viewmodel (DataContext).
I hope we are talking about the same problem.

Comment: I think the quesion was about assigning of event handler from child control's code-behind method to click event of other element in parent control via XAML.

Comment: @chameleon86 is right, the view-model is not involved in any way.